# Overview page for PyMonad on BitBucket

Tags: python, bitbucket

PyMonad is a Python library for Monads and related elements. It's available on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/jason_delaat/pymonad/). When I first accessed it I got an [Overview page](https://bitbucket.org/jason_delaat/pymonad/overview) (which was very well done). The text of that page is in the [README.txt](https://bitbucket.org/jason_delaat/pymonad/src/master/README.txt) file. I downloaded the entire repo successfully.

Now when I go to the [Overview page](https://bitbucket.org/jason_delaat/pymonad/overview) I am redirected to the [source page](https://bitbucket.org/jason_delaat/pymonad/src/master/). There seems to be no way to get back to the Overview page.

A Google cache of the Overview page looks like [this](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:62c-6IwiRXkJ:https://bitbucket.org/jason_delaat/pymonad%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). Notice that it lists [Overview](https://bitbucket.org/jason_delaat/pymonad/overview) as the first link on the left navigation bar. But the source page does not list Overview, and as I said, there seems to be no way (for me) to get back to it.

Fortunately, the content is in the `README.txt` file. It is also available on the [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/PyMonad/).

My question is, why is the [Overview page](https://bitbucket.org/jason_delaat/pymonad/overview) apparently blocked by an automatic redirect (at least for me after downloading) on the Bitbucket site, and is there a way to unblock/unredirect it?

Comment: The contents of the "overview page" are shown right after the directory view on the "source page", so I can't reproduce that.

Comment: I was afraid others might not be able to reproduce the problem. Did you try downloading the code? That's when it seemed to go bad for me.